# For loop not working as expected from a C programmer's perspective

Tags: functions, output-formatting

Why does `Print[n]` produce output inside a `For` loop, while `Sqrt[n]` (as well as many other functions) does not?

[image]

In addition can you get `Print[n]` to single space its output?

Comment: `For[start,test,incr,body]`  evaluates `body`, but _"Unless an explicit Return is used, the value returned by For is Null."_

Comment: Well, as a C programmer what output would you expect if you run `for (i=0; i < 5; i++) { sqrt(i); }`? It's exactly the same thing. `printf` prints to the screen and `sqrt` doesn't. Furthermore, `for` in C is not an expression so it doesn't have a value (even if the `sqrt` inside does).  In Mathematica everything is an expression, but where it doesn't make sense to return a value, `Null` is returned.

Comment: "In addition can you get Print[n] to single space its output?" Each `Print` will create a separate [cell](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithCells.html) in the notebook. Thus this is not about single or double-spacing but about the top and bottom margins of a `"Print"` style cell. This is defined by the stylesheet and can be changed. In command line mode, each `Print` outputs on a new line (with no empty lines inbetween).

Comment: If you have a C background, you might be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12). (This is not a direct comment on this question. It is entirely reasonable to want to understand how `For` works, but after that, it's probably better if you don't use it.)

Comment: To answer the 2nd part of your question about spacing, to get any kind formatting from `Print` you must wrap the expression you want to print with one Mathematica  many formatting functions. Since you new to Mathematica, I suggest you look at `Row` and `Column` for spacing control. Basic vertical spacing: `Print[Column[{a, b, c}, Spacings -> 0]]`. Basic horizontal spacing: `Print[Row[{a, b, c}, " "]]`.

Comment: @Szaboics  Of course C requires a printf inside a for loop to get any output, but because entering Sqrt[n] into the Mathematica frontend by itself produces output, I though that putting Sqrt[n] inside a for loop would produce output for each iteration, the same as unrolling the loop by hand. Fortunately, however using Print[Sqrt[n]] inside the for loop does work, as in For[n = 0, n < 5, n++, Print[Sqrt[n]]]. By the way, thanks for the link explaining more about For[] and Do[].

Answer (score 3):

Because `Print` puts text on your screen as a side effect. The result of a `For` loop, however, is `Null`.

*Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language, very different from C. Using C programming style is inadvisable, especially because it will confuse you as a C programmer.

I suggest:

```
Table[Sqrt[n], {n,1,5}]
```

Comment: "The result of a For loop, however, is simply the last expression evaluated." Actually, it's always `Null`.

Comment: Right. Shows how often I use `For` in MMA.

Answer (score 1):

Another method, sticking  with `For`

```
Reap[For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Sow[Sqrt[i]]]][[2, 1]]
```

> {0, 1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}

Comment: Oh noes :p The horror...